# Is there another way around than using Amazon s3 storage for Amazon Transcribe?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-transcribe

I need to transcribe a series of videos to text for one of my applications. Is there any way of using local storage to proceed with a transcription job in Amazon transcribe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you need to download the transcription from S3 after the transcribe job finished.